# ¿Como puedo poner un enlace html que abra una aplicación lectora de pdf?

Tags: android, html

Como en android no se puede abrir un documento PDF en el navegador, me gustaría que mi aplicación web pudiera abrir una app como adobe acrobat y mandarle el documento a abrir. Consigo ir al market para abrir la aplicación, pero no abrirla directamente con el documento abierto.

```
<a href="intent://sdcard/documento.pdf/#Intent;scheme=application/pdf;package=com.adobe.reader;action=android.intent.action.VIEW;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.adobe.reader;end;">abrir pdf</a>
```

El documento texto.pdf está en la raiz del móvil.

Gracias

Comment: No te vale abrirlo con un intent?

Comment: Bienvenido Jose, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!. Especifica tu pregunta ya que el PDF se puede abrir en el navegador y en el WebView (existen opciones).

Comment: Es en local. Si meto una web en local en  un dispositivo android, el navegador no lo abre, sólo da la opción de descargarlo cuando ya está en el propio móvil.
Solo puedo usar elementos html. Si se puede crear el intent a través del html como en el enlace de arriba estupendo, pero no lo he conseguido.
No me vale hacer una aplicación android, puesto que la aplicación es web y el único fallo que tiene es este.

Comment: sigues sin encontrar solución?